# Bug of answering questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

For some reason, whenever I answer a question, under the 'unanswered' or 'questions' tab it says I asked it. even when I'm logged out. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't say you asked it. I assume you are referring to the fact that your username appears on the front page (http://unix.stackexchange.com) associated with the question. If you look closely, however, you'll see that you're marked as having answered, not asked:

[image: screenshot of the front page showing posts marked as asked, asnwered or modified]

As you can see above, the last person to act on the question is listed but they are listed with the action they took. So, if you answer, your username will appear and be shown as "answered by John". If you edit, it will appear next to "modified by" etc.

Compare that to what is shown on the questions page (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) where only the asker's name is shown:

[image: questions page]

Comment: But my user was shown there even when my answer wasn't marked as anwersed.

Comment: @John yes, it has nothing to do with accepting. You posted an answer, therefore you "answered" the question and that's what the site showed.